# .NET MVC 4 JSON Post/Put char limit in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using the PUT verb to send JSON to a MVC controller. When I reach a certain limit I get a 500 error. If I scale back the JSON I send, then it sends just fine... Does anyone know of a configuration in the web.config that will allow a larger amount of JSON to be passed to my application?

Comment: What is the size you are posting where you have trouble?

Comment: Do you have any details on which actual error you get on the server? Server log?

Comment: I don't see any details in the Server log...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer... My JSON object was quite large so .NET wouldn't allow it to pass due to a "security feature" The default is 2000, so I bumped it and it worked perfectly.

```
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="5000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach - 1**

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

**Approach - 2**

```
<location path="File Path or FileHandler.ashx">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="your value" maxRequestLength="Your value" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Using this approach, we can set the limits for specific page and not for the complete application.

**Approach - 3**

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="Your version" maxRequestLength="Your value" />
```

Using this approach, we can set the limits for complete application.

Comment: This doesn't work... I have these set to max int. If I cut the JSON size but increase the size of a field in the JSON, it goes through just fine, but it has something to do with the JSON length and not the content itself...

Comment: Worked for us here, just using Approach - 1. Our scenario was sending a large-for-json (100KB+) json object.

Answer (score 0):

Check the maxRequestLength in your web.config. If the data exceeds maxRequestLength, 500 status is returned.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="XXX" />
```

Note: if maxRequestLength isn't specified. Default value is 4MB.

If that doesn't work, try IIS's [Request Limits](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits). Documentation however says that 404 status should be returned.