# MVC 5 Ajax POST - action variable not recognizing ajax data variable

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a click function that grabs rows from an grid. The return value is a list of objects which represent each row. I use JSON.stringify so I can send the data to my SaveJobs action on my Home Controller. The following properties work and my controller action recognizes the data, but it is not in valid JSON format.

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
data: { data: JSON.stringify(editedRows) }
```

However, I found through research that the below method is preferred since it is a valid JSON format, but my data variable on my controller action is null (returning no data to perform my action on) and I could not debug the issue. Why does the action variable not recognize this? Thank you.

```
$('#SaveJobs').on('click', function () {

editedRows = getEditedRows();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    url: savePlannedJobsUrl,
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({ data: editedRows }),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (result) {

        if (result === 'Success') {
            alert('The records you have edited are saved');
        }
        else {
            alert('There was an error with the server. All records may not have been saved.');
        }

        $("*").css("cursor", "");
    },
    error: function (HtmlHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        var htmlObj = $.parseHTML(HtmlHttpRequest.responseText);
        var savedJson = JSON.stringify(editedRows);

        if (htmlObj !== null) {
            var htmlBody = htmlObj[htmlObj.length-1].outerText;;
        }

        tryToWriteError(htmlBody, savedJson);
    }
  });
return false;
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public string SaveJobs(string data)
{
    // CODE HERE
}
```

**ANSWER**:
I marked @Queti's answer, and more specific to my problem see the link in my comment that will help for MVC projects. That resolution will skip creating DTOs.

Comment: You need to see what the client is actually sending to the server. Use either the browser's developer tools or Fiddler.

Comment: the first approach, which works but is not valid JSON, is sending `data=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A7191....(more data here)` and the second approach, which is not working, but is valid JSON, is sending `{"data":[{"id":5207,"Comments"...(more code)}]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are sending in an array of objects, but your action method is expecting a string.

It appears that your `getEditedRows` method is returning an array of objects.

I recommend you create a model on the server that matches what you are passing in. Something like:

```
public class MyDto
{
  int id { get; set; }
  string comments { get; set; }
}
```

And then update your method signature to accept that as the parameter:

`public string SaveJobs(List<MyDto> data)`

Comment: is there a limit to how many objects can be sent back? Also, would the contentType be the default?

Comment: Yes, there is a limit, however, this can be configured: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788342/net-mvc-4-json-post-put-char-limit-in-web-config

Comment: hmm..two more items if you do not mind. Will the data map automatically to my DTO from the AJAX call? I am testing it now and all my properties are null. so the `<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>` works when I am sending objects? If so is that limit the number of objects?

Comment: for the mapping issue I found a resolution [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx/)