# Posting a large change set in MVC using Slickgrid

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, slickgrid

I am attempting to optimize an MVC app that utilizes SlickGrid for grid edits. The grid itself can be anywhere from 500-25,000 rows long and has roughly 40 columns. The grid itself works great, but I've had trouble posting changed data to my controller in order to then update a SQL-side table.

My saving troubles are caused by the POST limits in MVC. I have edited the maxAllowedLengths in my web.config and tried just about anything. But even if I could post infinite amounts of data, I think it's possible to work smarter, not harder.

Here's some attempted psuedo-code to show how I currently save data:

```
function Save(data)
{
     var changedData = [];
     for(i = 0; i < data.length, i++) {
         if(data[i].isChanged == 1)
         {
         changedData.push(data[i]); 
         //this array of changed objects only contains 
         //propertys/columns that actually can be changed. About 30 in total. 
         }
     }
     //I can currently POST a little more than 5000 rows, anything else and I get a 500 error due 
     //do the size of my JSON string.
     if (changedData.length < 5000)
     {
           $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: JSON.stringify(changedData),
           success: success
           }); 
     }else
     {
     //break changedData into chunks of 5000 and loop through the ajax call. 
     }
}
```

Here's how I'm attempting to save changes. This involves saving the changes in a queue, sending it to the controller, and then executing it sequentially on the data server-side.

```
   var pendingChanges = [];
   function Save(data)
   {        
      //I would like to be able to do this in one go instead of chunking out the changes 
      //and finding a way to store them server side before aggregating and running them. 
           $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: JSON.stringify(pendingChanges),
           success: success
           }); 
   }

   grid.OnCellChange(....)
   {
    //Update data in cell
    pendingChanges.push(ID:item.id, Property:xxx,Value:item.value,TimeStamp:now);
   }

   function massCellChange()
   {
     var changedRows = [];
     for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++;)
     {
      if (slickGridDataViewContainsThisItem)
       {
          changedRows.push(data[i].ID);
          //Update slickgrid
       }
     }
      pendingChanges.push(ID:[changedRows],Property:xxx,Value:item.value,TimeStamp:now);
   }
```

On the controller side, as long I can actually make it to the method, I have no problems. There I use a JavaScriptSerializer or do a JSONConvert to break out the changeset into my model.

I'm also completely open to any other patterns that can be used to save large changesets. There are some features that allow users to edit the entire grid in one go, however only those that are currently visible in the dataView, so the number of changes a single user can generate can be quite huge. I've thought of simply sending that global command as a single pending change, but have failed to find an elegant way to also POST which rows were visible when that change was run. (Setting the ID: property as an array of IDs has proved not work. Same issue with POST limitations.)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your solution looks okay. I am sure that there is a way to get rid of the length limitation. Maybe this answer could work for you. It helped me in one of my projects where I was transfering Megabytes of Json data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788342/net-mvc-4-json-post-put-char-limit-in-web-config

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time, so I thought I would post my workaround. Instead of attempting to post lots of work after the user attempted clicked "save", I broke it up with an autosave. Essentially, each time a user made an edit, I would push an object with the column name,rowid, and its new value to an array. When the autosave fired, I would run through the queue of changes, taking only the latest value for each cell. Seems simple enough and sort of like a 'duh' moment. Doing this improved the response time of my app. Users were also happier that work was being saved continuously instead of just at the end of a task.

By sending just the simplified queue of columns, rowIDs, a new value, I was able to cut down a lot of what was being sent. I think could run through that "script" of changes to rebuild the objects in my middle end to then update the database with.